# Ruby: irb doesn't work on Windows

Tags: ruby, irb

I've installed Ruby 1.93 in my windows 7 PC using Ruby 1.9.3-p194 one click installer. I can use `ruby` command to interpret files, but when I type `irb` it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\Acer>irb
F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2111:in `expand_path': non-absolute home
(ArgumentError)
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2111:in `_rl_read_init_file'

        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2094:in `rl_read_init_file'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:2515:in `readline_initialize
_everything'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:3746:in `rl_initialize'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rbreadline.rb:4758:in `readline'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/readline.rb:40:in `readline'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/input-method.rb:115:in `gets'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:139:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:273:in `signal_status'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:138:in `block in eval_input'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in `call'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:188:in `buf_input'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:103:in `getc'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:205:in `match_io'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/slex.rb:75:in `match'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:286:in `token'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:262:in `lex'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:233:in `block (2 levels) in each_top
_level_statement'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `loop'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:229:in `block in each_top_level_stat
ement'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `catch'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:228:in `each_top_level_statement'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
        from F:/Programs/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I installed Ruby on `F:/Programs/Ruby193` folder and added `F:/Programs/Ruby193/bin` in my `PATH`.
I also tried with Ruby 1.87 but got the same error.

Comment: The second post down on [this guy's blog](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2011_02_01_archive.html) looks a lot like your issue and he suggests it's caused by Cygwin.  Could that be it?

Comment: Yes.. I've Cygwin installed in my computer. I'm checking this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the solution from Pete's comment. I have `Cygwin` installed in my computer which was causing the problem (Not sure why). I have just typed this in the command line: `set HOME=`
and `irb` started working!

You can also see [this link](http://royontechnology.blogspot.com/2011/02/cygwin-and-irb.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem to start IRB in Ruby 1.9.3 related to fiddle you can do this:

In  `rubyxxx\lib\ruby\site_ruby\x.x.x\rbreadline.rb` replace:

This:

```
  require 'fiddle'
  class Win32API
    DLL = {}
    TYPEMAP = {"0" => Fiddle::TYPE_VOID, "S" => Fiddle::TYPE_VOIDP, "I" => Fiddle::TYPE_LONG}
    CALL_TYPE_TO_ABI = {:stdcall => 1, :cdecl => 1, nil => 1} #Taken from Fiddle::Importer

    def initialize(dllname, func, import, export = "0", calltype = :stdcall)
      @proto = import.join.tr("VPpNnLlIi", "0SSI").chomp('0').split('')
      handle = DLL[dllname] ||= Fiddle.dlopen(dllname)
      @func = Fiddle::Function.new(handle[func], TYPEMAP.values_at(*@proto), CALL_TYPE_TO_ABI[calltype])
    end

    def call(*args)
      args.each_with_index do |x, i|
        args[i], = [x == 0 ? nil : x].pack("p").unpack("l!*") if @proto[i] == "S"
        args[i], = [x].pack("I").unpack("i") if @proto[i] == "I"
      end
      @func.call(*args).to_i || 0
    end
```

With:

```
  require 'dl'
  class Win32API
    DLL = {}
    TYPEMAP = {"0" => DL::TYPE_VOID, "S" => DL::TYPE_VOIDP, "I" => DL::TYPE_LONG}

    def initialize(dllname, func, import, export = "0", calltype = :stdcall)
      @proto = [import].join.tr("VPpNnLlIi", "0SSI").sub(/^(.)0*$/, '\1')
      handle = DLL[dllname] ||= DL.dlopen(dllname)
      @func = DL::CFunc.new(handle[func], TYPEMAP[export.tr("VPpNnLlIi", "0SSI")], func, calltype)
    end

    def call(*args)
      import = @proto.split("")
      args.each_with_index do |x, i|
        args[i], = [x == 0 ? nil : x].pack("p").unpack("l!*") if import[i] == "S"
        args[i], = [x].pack("I").unpack("i") if import[i] == "I"
      end
      ret, = @func.call(args)
      return ret || 0
    end
```

Comment: There is no `rbreadline.rb` in my install. What to do then?

Comment: @Snailedlt In Ruby 1.9.3 usually the file exists, In clean installations too, maybe you have some custom installation

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/). I have 64-bit Windows 7 and ruby 1.9.3-p125, and everything works smoothly with DevKit.

```
d:\>systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise

d:\>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

d:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> 2+2
=> 4
irb(main):002:0> exit
```